# Having a html element flash a background color and fade to another

Tags: javascript, css, firefox

I'm looking for a light weight solution to have an HTML element like a div or an li flash one background color, like solid green, then fade to another color over some time period like fading to white over 3 secs.

I don't want to include some massive library like jquery, and I only need this to work on Firefox, the most light weight the solution the better!

I know I could do this with javascript fairly easily, but it won't be very lightweight and I figure there must be some way to do this with CSS, that would be the ideal solution in my opinion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Use an `animation`](http://cssdeck.com/labs/z1626xdq). Keep in mind you may need to prefix this to get it work on all target browsers.

HTML

```
<div id='flashMe'></div>
```

CSS

```
#flashMe {
  height:500px;
  width:500px;
  background:black;

  animation: flash 3s forwards linear normal;
}
@keyframes flash {
  0% {
    background:black;
  }
  4% {
    background:green;
  }
  100% {
    background:red;
  }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You could take a look at CSS3 Animations. I am not that good with CSS3 so I can't provide any solution but afaik CSS3 can do stuff like this.

http://www.w3schools.com/css3/css3_animations.asp